# Почему не удается получить ответ от сервера soap wsdl php Curl?

Tags: php, curl, soap, wsdl

Сам не дружу пока что с soap wsdl, хоть и прочитал кучу статей про них, но никак не укладываются в голове базовые основы.
В интеренете нашел пример обращения к серверу через Curl и подставил свои логин, пароль и wsdl:

```
<?php

  $query = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
<m:Calc xmlns:m="http://www.cargo3.ru">
<m:login>test</m:login>     //login
<m:password>2016</m:password>       //password
<m:data>
<m:Key>Destinations</m:Key>
<m:List>
<m:Key>Destination</m:Key>
<m:Fields>
<m:Key>SenderGeography</m:Key>
<m:Value>cf862f56-442d-11dc-9497-0015170f8c09</m:Value>
<m:ValueType>string</m:ValueType>
</m:Fields>
<m:Fields>
<m:Key>RecipientGeography</m:Key>
<m:Value>cf862f56-442d-11dc-9497-0015170f8c09</m:Value>
<m:ValueType>string</m:ValueType>
</m:Fields>
<m:Fields>
<m:Key>TypeOfCargo</m:Key>
<m:Value>4aab1fc6-fc2b-473a-8728-58bcd4ff79ba</m:Value>
<m:ValueType>string</m:ValueType>
</m:Fields>
<m:Fields>
<m:Key>Weight</m:Key>
<m:Value>1</m:Value>
<m:ValueType>float</m:ValueType>
</m:Fields>
<m:Fields>
<m:Key>VolumeWeight</m:Key>
<m:Value>1</m:Value>
<m:ValueType>float</m:ValueType>
</m:Fields>
<m:Fields>
<m:Key>Volume</m:Key>
<m:Value>1</m:Value>
<m:ValueType>float</m:ValueType>
</m:Fields>
<m:Fields>
<m:Key>Qty</m:Key>
<m:Value>1</m:Value>
<m:ValueType>int</m:ValueType>
</m:Fields>
</m:List>
</m:data>
<m:parameters xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<m:Key>Parameters</m:Key>
<m:List>
<m:Key>ipaddress</m:Key>
<m:Value xsi:type="xs:string">10.0.0.1</m:Value>
<m:ValueType>string</m:ValueType>
</m:List>
</m:parameters>
</m:Calc>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array(
    $ch,
    array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'http://lk-test.cse.ru/1c/ws/web1c.1cws?wsdl',        //wsdl
      CURLOPT_VERBOSE => FALSE,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
      CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $query,
      CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: text/xml')
    )
  );
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  header('Content-Type: text/xml');
  print_r($response);

?>
```

В ответе приходит только это:

**This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.**

Что делаю не так? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: @TotalPusher теперь пустую страницу возвращает

Comment: @TotalPusher извините, может я не правильно задал вопрос. Мне нужно перетянуть с сайта http://www.cse.ru/sitecontent/city-mosrus/lang-rus/content/131/ калькулятор на мой сайт. С помощью скрипта выше я думал что на моем сайте отобразится сам калькулятор, но отображается только сам xml документ

Comment: На той странице калькулятор работает через ajax, и без soap. `http://lk-test.cse.ru/1c/ws/web1c.1cws?wsdl` - откуда взяли? Откройте Хром, перейдите на https://lk.cse.ru/cse/calc, вкладка сеть, XHR, там все запросы

Comment: @TotalPusher wsdl взял с их api https://lk.cse.ru/files/uploads/extended_api_2017_09_07.pdf 98 страница там описано, но как с эти взаимодействовать непонятно мне.

Comment: Совсем не понятно, что хотите сделать? Получить расчетные значения (отправит данные, получить данные), или перетянуть весь калькулятор, включая часть верстки?

Comment: @TotalPusher сейчас попробую объяснить подробнее - хочу перетянуть весь функционал калькулятора, но набросать свои стили к инпутам, div.... и т.д

Comment: Используйте обертку типа wsdl2phpgenerator и не заморачивайтесь с ручным созданием запроса. Да, и еще - бывает так что адрес сервиса и его WSDL определение - разные, эта библиотека учтет и это.

Comment: @TotalPusher а не будет слишком нагло если я спрошу у Вас как этой штукой пользоваться wsdl2phpgenerator? а то гитхабом не пользовался никогда)

Comment: Для вас самым простым будет "Clone or download", "Download ZIP"

Comment: @TotalPusher а как Вам можно в личку написать, если можно? или на почту

Comment: Нет, не надо. Цель стековерфлоу - делиться знаниями с другими. Пишите тут.

Comment: @TotalPusher не подскажите как пользоваться этим wsdl2php генератором? Скачал "cloneOrDowndload" распаковал, а дальше что делать не понял пока. Пробовал какой-то Composer поставить, даже не понял вышло ли это у меня или нет

Comment: wsdl2php я не использую, это @DanielProtopopov советует. Если про [этот пакет](https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator), то он ставится через композер. И ничего скачивать не надо. Как использовать [на английском](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) и [на русском](http://getcomposer.ucoz.org/publ/kniga/nachalo_raboty/2-1-0-1). Попробуйте как это работает. Будет большим плюсом как программисту. Как поставите с помощью композера этот пакет, смотрите примеры на гитхабе.

Comment: @TotalPusher спасибо большое в любом случае